# Is there a way to edit UGC post via api on linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, ugc

Is there a way to edit a post or it's description once you have created it with video attachment on linkedin's UGC api?

Here is a link to it's documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?tabs=http

My main goal is to create a post with video attachment (as a file, not as a link) on linkedin using its api, and be able to edit it's text later.

Any help or idea is welcome!